# Inequality of area of two triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with sides $a,b,c$ and $A_1B_1C_1$ be another triangle with sides $a+\frac{b}2$, $b+\frac{c}2$, $c+\frac{a}2$. Prove that:

$$\frac94[ABC]\le[A_1B_1C_1]$$

I tried using Heron's formula, but it is not getting me to the answer. Can anyone help? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Heron's formula,

$[ABC]=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a+b+c)(b+c-a)(a+c-b)(a+b-c)}$

$[A_1B_1C_1]=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\frac{3(a+b+c)}{2}(b+c-a+\frac{a+c-b}{2})(a+c-b+\frac{a+b-c}{2})(a+b-c+\frac{b+c-a}{2})}$

Set $b+c-a=x$, $a+c-b=y$, $a+b-c=z$,

Enough to show:

$\frac{27}{8}xyz\leq(x+\frac{y}{2})(y+\frac{z}{2})(z+\frac{x}{2}) $,

i.e

$27xyz\leq(x+x+y)(y+y+z)(z+z+x) $,

Use AM-GM for 3 terms of RHS.

For example, $x+x+y\geq 3\sqrt[3]{x^2y}$.

QED.